# Atualizações de APK não aplicadas corretamente

Tags: android, proguard-android

Desenvolvi um aplicativo há 2 anos e temos atualizado na Google Play assinando sempre com um certificado jks e cifrando com o ProGuard. Esse aplicativo foi atualizado em algumas versões.

Mesmo **não** utilizando "smart updates" que o Android permite, em certas situações e alguns aparelhos, o aplicativo é "pseudo-atualizado" no telefone do usuário.

Fiz uma publicação de testes retirando o ProGuard e não ocorreu este problema. Mas é raro de ocorrer e estou com dificuldades de reproduzir esse defeito para tentar provocar mais vezes o problema.

Li sobre o algoritmo de delta para reduzir download desnecessário sobre smartUpdates mas não cita nada referente ao ProGuard justamente porque ele "embaralha" e a comparação de diferença de blocos fica furada, publicados aqui http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6563072.

Mas não ajudou efetivamente a resolver o problema, o artigo só explica "como" são realizados os smart updates. Mesmo desabilitado, estou tendo alguns problemas.

Infelizmente fica difícil detectar se é problema realmente do aparelho do usuário, pois aconteceu outros casos. Se é a versão da Google Play do aparelho do usuário, se é o ProGuard etc. Um defeito difícil de reproduzir.

Alguém já passou por situação parecida e conhece alguma solução?

Um abraço a todos!